# NoseGAE ImportError: No module named contrib.appengine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, testing, nose, nose-gae

I am trying to integrate [nose](/questions/tagged/nose) and NoseGAE in a Python project.

Tried running:

```
nosetests tests --with-gae in virtualenv
```

> ERROR:     from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
>              ImportError: No module named contrib.appengine

The weird thing is it resolves everything else `oauth2client`, checks the `contrib.appengine`, and exits in the Python site-package.

Comment: Check your `sys.path`. Unfortunately the gcloud sdk provides `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/` which does not have `contrib` in it and it is probably in your path before the `oauth2client` in your site packages.

Comment: Thanks that was it

Comment: I'll write it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sys.path`. Unfortunately the gcloud sdk provides `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/` which does not have `contrib` in it and it is probably in your path before the `oauth2client` in your site packages.